# Could "allow for" be replaced by "allow" in this particular case?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

This [book](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCI.pdf) says

> ...
>
> In the next section we introduce a stochastic process called a Markov
>   chain which does `allow for` correlations and also has enough structure
>   and simplicity to `allow for` computations to be carried out. We will
>   also see that Markov chains can be used to model a number of the above
>   examples.

Cambridge gives this [explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allow-for-sb-sth) of allow for

> to consider someone or something when you are planning something

and this [explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allow) of allow

> to give permission for someone to do something, or to not prevent something from happening

Although there seems to be some [nuances](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/whats-the-difference-between-allow-and-allow-for) between "allow" and "allow for".

Could "allow for" be replaced by "allow" in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the referent is the Markov chain, I see no issue with the use of "allow," as it is the chain that is, by design, carrying out correlations and computations. If, however, the referent is their introducing a stochastic process, "allow for" is appropriate. They themselves do not execute the correlations and computations, but they set in motion a process in which they can be. So, in effect, they *allow for* the correlations and computations the Markhov chain *allows* to be carried out to happen.

Read the sentence again. It's obvious the referent is the chain,  The structure of the chain is mentioned before computations is brought in. This noticed, I think "allow" is best.